# .Net Validation controls Issue - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Experiencing a strange issue this morning. In order to validate my form, I added, as usual, .Net validation controls. Being not the first time I've done this, I can't understand for the life of me, why, as soon as I add a validator, I keep getting this error in the browser web dev console window:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < localhost:49969/WebResource.axd?d=GUktuIIVMvnjYj9xJJ6L3zN4f2tXECMYpvoF7TwMD…b07fk_FC3sb0L-gISjvvX-BESM2omajsyO9rvkGHmflG11y2Ng1&t=635297969564503053:3
```

The thing is that, it doesn't really affect the validation in a way, because if I click the submit button, the page refresh (full refresh) and if my fields are empty, it will display the error messages. But the behavior is not normal, you see. Usually the page is suppose to do a partial refresh, like an update panel, and the error message display as soon as submit is clicked. Or even better, if a user enters some characters in a textbox, change focus into another textbox, comes back to the first one, delete the text and clicks away in order for the textbox to lose focus again, the validator is suppose to fire dynamically and display the error message (no submit clicked).

If I remove the validators, the error message is not displayed.

Do I have something that is conflicting with the validation? Anyone encountered this behavior?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with a MasterPage setup.

MasterPage (Header and footer content stripped out, not relevant to the problem, contained simple bootstrap syntax):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/bs3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="/css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/gs/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<%--Google Analytics--%>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="header">
        <%--Header div--%>
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <%--Footer div--%>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Form:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_Contact" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <title><asp:Literal ID="litpagetitle" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, ContactPageTitle %>" /></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="/js/GMap.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="contact-container">
                <%--CONTACT INFOS--%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="map-container">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <%--GOOGLEMAP CONTAINER--%>
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <asp:Panel ID="PanelContact" runat="server">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-name" class="contact-label"><asp:Literal ID="litName" meta:resourcekey="formName" runat="server"></asp:Literal></label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-mail" class="contact-label"><asp:Literal ID="LitMail" meta:resourcekey="formMail" runat="server"></asp:Literal></label> <br />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMail" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtMail" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMail" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-msg" class="contact-label">Message</label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="txtMsg" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" class="form-control contact-textarea" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class="default-btn brochure-btn contact-form-btn" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" Text="Soumettre" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="PanelConfirmation" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <h1>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h1>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the validators, 'cause this is the part that looks sketchy to me:

<asp:Literal ID="litpagetitle" runat="server" Text="" <%$ Resources:Global, ContactPageTitle %>" />

Comment: @June Paik: Let me check and remove that part: EDIT: Error still there, so no, it's not that